# Why do RX-OK and TX-OK increase

Tags: linux, netstat

I'm testing my linux server with the command `netstat -i`.

[image]

I just want to know what `enp2s0f0` means. Each time that I execute `netstat -i`, its RX-OK and TX-OK always increase. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enp2s0f0` - is your primary network interface. About the convention of naming network interfaces you can read on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Network_Device_Naming).

The **RX-OK/ERR/DRP/OVR** columns give statistics about the packets that have been received by the interface. **OK** stands for packets correctly received.

**TX-OK** stands for packets correctly transmitted respectively.

Counters always increase for 'TX-OK', it means that outgoing traffic is bigger than incoming for your server.

Comment: Both counters increase with time: received packets increase **RX-OK** and transmitted packets increase **TX-OK**. E.g. in the screenshot, 11 packets were received and 8 were transmitted. Why do you think that ougoing traffic is bigger than incoming?

Comment: So does it mean that my server has always communication with the Internet or LAN? If I cut off the ethernet cable, it will stop increasing?

Comment: @Nick, yes you are right about these screenshots that 11 packets were received and 8 were transmitted. I meant overall statistics. Yves, yes, the server has network activity continuously. After unplugging Ethernet cable, counters will stop increase.